# python 3.x urllib.request.urlopen cyrillic content on site -> 403

Tags: python, urllib, cyrillic

```
import urllib.request

def forum(request):
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.ru") as url:
        s = url.read().decode().encode('utf-8')
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

I get "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" because of the Cyrillic alphabet on the site.

Example http://hostdjango.pythonanywhere.com/

If I replace the "google.ru" on the "google.com" then all is ok.

Comment: There is likely some other reason why you get a 403 error. It has nothing to do with the content on the site. Try printing out the `HTTPError`’s content to see if you get any more information on the error.

Comment: I add User-Agent, but it did not help.